# Modifying Summation using Recursion

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

How do I modify the summation method using recursive definition to get the sum of 1 to `N` via - `(1 to N/2)` + `((N/2+1) to N)`?
I'm confused a bit here, I've typed out something along the lines of this, but it's not recursion:

```
public static int Sum(int n){
    int sum1 = 0;
    int sum2 = 0;
    int totalSum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n/2; i++){
        sum1 += i;
    }
    for(int i = n/2 + 1; i <= n; i++){
        sum2 += i;
    }
    totalSum = sum1 + sum2;
    return totalSum;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

First off, your implementation is not recursive.

Your question states the right algorithm: to sum the values between 1 and `n`, you can sum them between 1 and `n/2`, then between `n/2 + 1` and `n`. This means we need to create a helper function `sum(int a, int b)` whose goal will be to return the sum of all the values between `a` and `b`.

- The base case is when `a == b`: in this case, the helper should just return `a`.
- In the recursive step, we do the previous algorithm: sum from `a` to `(a+b)/2` and sum from `(a+b)/2 + 1` to `b`.

This would be an implementation:

```
public static int sum(int a, int b) {
    if (a == b) {
        return a;
    }
    int middle = (a + b) / 2;
    return sum(a, middle) + sum(middle + 1, b);
}
```

with this, the initial task becomes:

```
public static int sum(int n) {
    return sum(1, n);
}
```

Some samples:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(sum(4)); // prints 10
    System.out.println(sum(5)); // prints 15
    System.out.println(sum(6)); // prints 21
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I don't completely understand how it works. How does this actually give you the summation of the numbers? I understand that the second segment of code sends the parameters of 1 and then n (which the user inputs in my code), but don't get the top code segment and how it actually does the math... Sorry, can you dumb it down for me a bit?

Comment: @JohnBarr We define a method `sum(a, b)` which will return the sum of all integer values between `a` and `b`. As you said, we can split this in 2: first calculate the sum between `a` and the middle element, then the sum between the middle element and `b`. The first case, sum between `a` and the middle element can be expressed with `sum(a, b)` again with `b` being the middle element now; that's where the recursion kicks in.